# Maximum sum of cathetii (shorter arms of triangle ) with hypotenuse length =1

Tags: calculus, geometry

A rectangular triangle has its hypotenuse with length = 1.

Prove that the sum of the shorter sides will be maximum when the triangle is

isosceles.

I have no ideas how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the following figure

[image]

it becomes clear that the problem is to maximize the following expression in $0\le\alpha \le \frac{\pi}2$:

$$\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha).$$

Deriving this expression with respect to $\alpha$ (and setting the result equalt 0) we get the following equation yielding the number we are looking for:

$$\sin(\alpha)=\cos(\alpha).$$

Considering the shape of the trig functions, the solution is at $$\alpha=\frac{\pi}4.$$

**Alternative (elementary solution**

If someone is not familiar with teh concept of the derivative will be able to solve the proble by looking at the graph (yellow) of the sum to be maximized:

[image]

The maximum is obviously taken in the middle. (The cosine is the mirror image of the sine about the vertical line drawn at the intersection.)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), $$\dfrac a{\sin A}=\dfrac b{\sin B}=\dfrac c{\sin90^\circ}$$

$\implies a=c\sin A,b=c\sin B=c\sin(90^\circ-B)=c\cos A$

$\implies a+b=c(\sin A+\cos A)=c\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+A\right)$

**Method** $\#1:$

$(\sin A+\cos A)^2+(\sin A-\cos A)^2=\cdots=2$

So, $(\sin A+\cos A)^2$ and hence $(\sin A+\cos A)$ will be maximum if $(\sin A-\cos A)^2=0$

**Method** $\#2:$

Now $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+A\right)\le1$

the equality occurs when $\dfrac\pi4+A=2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

But $0<A<\pi$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, i can. I think solution of the problem simpler. zoli has given it

Comment: @EvgenySemyonov, I avoided calculus.

Comment: @EvgenySemyonov Why didn't you include the "calculus" tag, then?

Comment: @David Mitra , Sorry i didn't care